# Get rid of Wordpress navigation menu div

Tags: php, wordpress, class, html

I am trying to create a navigation menu for a custom Wordpress theme using the `wp_nav_menu()` function. However, an when I use the function and reload the webpage, an annoying `<div>` html element appears and uses the class I want to style my `<ul>` with. Has anyone came across this issue before and how can I fix this?

The structure at the moment is like this: 
`<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>Menu Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>`

I would like it to look like this:
  `<ul class="nav">
    <li>Menu Item</li>
  </ul>`
Many thanks

Comment: try setting two argument on wp_nav_menu(), `wp_nav_menu('container' => '', 'container_class' => '')`

Comment: @Shazzad still no luck I'm afraid

Comment: Can you please show us how you're utilizing `wp_nav_menu`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs for [wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) you can use `wp_nav_menu(array('container' => false))` to disable the container.

Edit: You have also have to set the `theme_location` option so the fallback doesn't get triggered.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove container div then, you need to mention theme location.

```
  wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'secondary-menu','container' => 'none','menu'=>'Secondary') );
```